# linearLayout not set to vertical orientation

Tags: android, orientation, android-linearlayout

I am extending the LinearLayout class, but there is some problem with the orientation.
I am adding this view that I am creating to other Linearlayout, and still it is set to horizontal.
Here is the code:

```
package com.simplemathgame;

import java.util.Date;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;

public class GraphBar extends LinearLayout {
    private Date date;
    private int totalDrills;
    private int rightDrills;
    private int score;
    private int height;
    private final int widht = 30;
    private final int totHeight = 300;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams barParams;

    public GraphBar(Context context, int totalDrills, int rightDrills, Date date) {
        super(context);
        this.date = date;
        this.rightDrills = rightDrills;
        this.totalDrills = totalDrills;

        this.setScore();
        setParams();
        this.barParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,this.widht);
    }

    private void setScore(){
        this.height = (this.rightDrills / this.totalDrills) * totHeight;
    }

    private void setParams(){
        this.barParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(this.height,this.widht);
        this.barParams.setMargins(5, 0, 0, 0);
        this.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
        this.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        this.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        this.setLayoutParams(this.barParams);
    }
}
```

I tried to see it in both the emulator and my asus tablet.
any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry this doesn't answer your question but I'm just wondering why you would extend any type of layout / viewgroup class without enhancing its layout / viewgroup functionality. That's not really how OO design is meant to work. For instance, why would a layout / viewgroup need to know what the date is?

Comment: because it would be a graph bar, and when the user will hold touch it he would see see the date.

Comment: I still don't understand your logic - you can do everything in your `setParams()` method in a layout XML file but I suppose it's up to you how you want to do it. One possible reason for your problem though is `LinearLayout.LayoutParams(int width, int height)` - you're setting it with `height, width`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call this method in Constructor of the class that extends LinearyLayout   `setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);`